# How do I fix this JSON Code? I am getting an "undefined" error

Tags: json

I am very new to JSON (as in a few days into using it) and I can't get my head around what is wrong with this code. I have copy/pasted it and modified it to my needs carefully a few times and I am still getting this error code:

```
    Error: Parse error on line 3:
    ... "product_id": {         Product: Id     },      "
    ----------------------^
    Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

Here is my code:

```
{
    "image": {
        "product_id": {
            Product: Id
        },
        "position": 1,
        "src": {
            GWP Variant Image
        },
        "variant_ids": [{
            Variants: Id
        }]
    }
}
```

PS: I hope I understood the post formatting instructions correctly. This is my first post.

Comment: This is not a valid json at all. property values are either numbers, boolean (ie `true` or `false`) or strings. If they are strings they have to be enclosed in double quotes `"`. Also property names have to be enclosed in doublequotes. So for instance `{"Product": "Id"}` instead of `{Product: Id}` (if `Id` is non numeric). Further more an object consists of key-value pairs. So something like `{ GWP Variant Image}` is invalid

Comment: Thank you @derpirscher! I have learned two things from your answer. The first is that I did not supply enough information. The json was being used with Shopify api in an app called Parabola and {Product: Id} was a call to a table. The second thing I learned from this was that I needed to put quotes around the outside of {GWP Variant Image} because it was pointing at a web address. You solved my problem even though I did a poor job of describing my issue (mostly because I am still learning). Appreciate the time you took to answer this!